# Reactive-Redux Store.select firing twice

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

What is the advantage of defining an action pipeline through a behaviorSubject and subscribing ngrx/store as Observer to it?

eg.

```
SomeModel() {
  actionPipelines = new BehaviorSubject<Action>({type:null, payload:null});

  actionPipelines.filter(Filter1).map(Map1).mergeMap(Svc1(),SomeAction1());
  actionPipelines.filter(Filter2).map(Map2).mergeMap(Svc2(),SomeAction2());
  Observable.merge(actionPipelines).subscribe(store);
  //Data is manipulated in Reducer code and stored under store.dataReducer
  this.storedData$ = this.store.select<Data>('dataReducer').map(someExpr);

  loadData() { this.actionPipeline.next(Filter2); }
}


@Component(
  selector: 'component',
  template: '<div>Data Display {model.storedData$ | async}</div>'
)
MyComponent(model: SomeModel) {
  constructor() { this.model.loadData(); }
}
```

Comment: Not sure to which part you are referring that fires twice but any operator will fire once for each subscription.  In your code you have a subscribe and a async pipe which would be two subscriptions.   So say you use async pipe 5 times in a template then you'll have your operators such as map and filter run 5 times.  There is a operator called share that is supposed to change some of that but I'm not familiar enough with it to know when it is right to use it.

Comment: As far as the pipeline question I'm having the same debate with the architect where I work.  I see it being done in ngrx examples but I see no clear advantage.  Just seems like a coding style choice but there may be a deeper reason.

Comment: I misunderstood the whole thing. store.select will fire everytime there is an operation on store. In the code snippet above it was not apparent because no store operation like store.dispatch is shown in the map(Map1), and store was getting modified by reducer after the mergeMap call. So it was firing twice. If we introduce more store operations in the pipeline, it becomes evident. Since the question has inadequate info, if deemed inappropriate by community, I will delete/edit it.

Comment: Regarding the approach, I felt while implementing it in a non behaviorSubject way, the subscriptions become synchronous. This creates memory leakage and boiler plate to remove them and side effects. So, my understanding is, this pipeline approach is enabling a framework which deals with synchronous mechanism (user interaction) to work with asynchronous technology (http in ng2, rxjs). **Couldn't post the synchronous code variant in comment**.